# How should I translate もとから、わかれてできたもの?

Tags: word-choice

「もとから、わかれてできたもの。」

It's one of the meanings for the kanji 子 on my book. There are two examples for this meaning: 子音 and 利子.

In kanji, it should be 「元から、分かれて出来た物。」. The first verb is from 分かれる, not the potential form of 分かる.

"Something separeted (by itself?) and made (by who?) from (what?)."

I don't understand the explanation even with the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

分かれる and 出来る are both plain **intransitive** verbs, and the original sentence has no passive voice at all. (分かれる happens to end with れる, but it's not a passive marker but a part of the dictionary form of this verb.) However, you are trying to use the English passive voice ("～ed by ～") to translate it. Something like this is sometimes unavoidable, but in this case, it can make it unnecessarily harder for you to make sense of the original sentence.

You can translate this sentence using English intransitive verbs like so:

> 元から、分かれて出来た物
> something that separated from its origin and (then) came into existence

This can be paraphrased like "something that came into existence after separating from its origin". This 元 is a noun that roughly means *origin*, *source*, *root*, *base*, etc.

So this definition is basically saying the kanji 子 can refer to anything that is *derivative*, *subordinate* or *subsidiary*. 利子 ("interest") refers to money that derives from something. 子音 ("consonant") refers to a sound that can attach to a 母音 ("vowel") but cannot stand alone (this is not true in English, but it's true in the Japanese sound system).